# Finding a file by md5sum

Tags: bash, find, md5, md5sum

Given the md5sum of a file, I want to know if anywhere else in the directory tree is another file with the same md5sum (but maybe under a different name). How can I do that in bash?

P.S.: To emphasize, this should work for the entire tree below a given directory, i.e. must work recursively not just in the current directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `find` to recursively test all files:

```
find . -type f -exec \
bash -c 'md5sum "$0" | grep -q 2690d194b68463c5a6dd53d32ba573c7 && echo $0' {} \;
```

Here, `md5sum` outputs the MD5 sum and the file name. You need to `grep` it for the actual MD5 sum as there is no switch to have it just output the sum alone.

You can check the MD5 sum much easier with `md5` if you're on BSD or OS X:

```
find . -type f -exec \
bash -c '[ "$(md5 -q "$0")" = 2690d194b68463c5a6dd53d32ba573c7 ] && echo $0' {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks slhck looks very interesting, but apparently my md5 command has no -q option; neither has my md5sum command. I am using Xubuntu. Also what is the {} \ for?

Comment: Sorry, I had the wrong BSD `md5` tool here. On Linux you need `md5sum`. I'll correct my post when I'm back on a computer. The {} is the file path for each file found. It gets passed to `sh`. The \; simply ends the `exec` call.

Answer (score 1):

The other solutions are good but I want to propose one with fewer spawned processes, which should be significantly faster for many small files, if you have GNU find:

```
find /path/to/tree -type f -exec md5sum \{\} + | sed -nre 's/^md5-to-search-for  //p'
```

or without GNU find:

```
find /path/to/tree -type f -print0 | xargs -r -0 -- md5sum | sed -nre 's/^md5-to-search-for  //p'
```

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing some of the solution from slhck, I've came up with

```
find . -type f -print0 | while read -r -d '' f;
do
 md5sum "$f" | grep "$1"
done
```

Where $1 is the first argument. If you want to check for a missing argument start the file with:

```
if [ -z "$1" ]
  then
    echo "No argument supplied"
    exit
fi
```

Comment: This breaks if files contain whitespace in their path. To iterate over files you should use `find` with `exec` or globbing (e.g. `**`)

Comment: Another option would be to use `-print0` in your `find` command, and `xargs -0`.  So, in this case, `find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 md5 | grep (your MD5 code)`

Comment: I like this solution a lot. However it gives me tons of messages on stderr: "md5sum: somefilename: No such file or directory". I wonder if there's a way to suppress that?

Comment: @gojira If you get a "no such file or directory" that is probably because the files contain whitespace, and brixenDK's command breaks on this (due to the `for f in …`). If one file was named `foo bar`, for example, it'd try to do an MD5 sum on `foo` and `bar`, which both don't exist. For a good explanation why this happens and how to avoid it, see: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs